# Problems when running GDC_prepare in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I'm trying to retrieve and prepare some data from GDC and I'm running the following code which I copy-pasted from this YouTube video:[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWXv9dUpxNE).

Below is the code:

```
library(TCGAbiolinks)
library(tidyverse)
library(maftools)
library(pheatmap)
library(SummarizedExperiment)


# get a list of projects
gdcprojects <- getGDCprojects()


# building a query
query_TCGA <- GDCquery(project = 'TCGA-BRCA',
                       data.category = 'Transcriptome Profiling')
output_query_TCGA <- getResults(query_TCGA)


# build a query to retrieve gene expression data ------------
query_TCGA <- GDCquery(project = 'TCGA-BRCA',
                       data.category = 'Transcriptome Profiling',
                       experimental.strategy = 'RNA-Seq',
                       workflow.type = 'STAR - Counts',
                       access = 'open',
                       barcode = c('TCGA-LL-A73Y-01A-11R-A33J-07', 'TCGA-E2-A1IU-01A-11R-A14D-07','TCGA-AO-A03U-01B-21R-A10J-07'))

getResults(query_TCGA)

# download data - GDCdownload
GDCdownload(query_TCGA)


# prepare data
tcga_brca_data <- GDCprepare(query_TCGA)
```

And after running the last line of code I get the following error message:

```
leted after 0 s 
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
i With name: 1.
Caused by error in `y[, 2:4]`:
! Can't subset columns past the end.
i Locations 2, 3, and 4 don't exist.
i There is only 1 column.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
Warning messages:
1: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat) 
2: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat) 
3: One or more parsing issues, call `problems()` on your data frame for details, e.g.:
  dat <- vroom(...)
  problems(dat)
```

I do not understand what is causing this error since I'm using the same code as in the video.

Comment: When I ran your code, everything worked as you probably expected when you ran it. The first thing I'd suggest is restarting your R session (assuming you're using RStudio), shift + cmd + o for Mac, or going to the _Session_ menu, _Restart R_, then run every line of code again. When running it, watch the console, to make sure that each task executes. (When I ran the query it took a while and failed to connect the first time.) If this doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated R and BiocManager and now that good works. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross-posted and answered at https://support.bioconductor.org/p/9149780/

Solution: Update packages.